# Смена цвета иконок статус бара

Tags: ios, objective-c

Пишу приложение под ios на objective-c.
Стоит задача сменить цвет иконок в статус баре во время работы с приложением. Возможно ли это? И если как, то каким способом? Пару вариантов смены цвета самого статус бара нашел, но не самих иконок.
Может кто либо помочь с решением?

Comment: иконки статус бара это время, батарейка и тд?

Comment: Да, именно они. Заказчику нужно чтобы все иконки статус бара были белыми.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068882/react-native-how-to-change-status-bar-icon-colors   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

цвет самих иконок изменить нельзя. можно изменить только цветовой стиль самого бара - UIStatusBarStyle.